# UWSC の BTN(LEFT,CLICK,X,Y,T)で、座標の代わりに、HTMLタグを指定したい

Tags: windows

[UWSC](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWSC) のフリーソフト版で BTN(LEFT,CLICK,X,Y,T)と書いている箇所を、座標の代わりにHTMLタグで指定したいのですが、どう書けばよいですか？
クリックしたいHTMLは、下記buttonタグです。

```
<button type="button" class="hoge">
  <div>
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](http://uwsc.s1007.xrea.com/dom/document/getelementsbyclassname/)で指定できます。

```
DIM elements = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("hoge")
elements.Item(0).click()
```

Comment: 「UWSC」は、「Internet Explorer」使用が前提なのですね。

Comment: 私は試していませんが[UwscWebDriver](http://uwsc.s1007.xrea.com/uwscwebdriver/)を使うことでIE以外も利用できるようです。